# git revision walk setup failed

Tags: git, github

Whenever I execute `git status`, I get this output:

> error: Could not read da1e8fd9f8afb20331f685b5c9448bd452658332 fatal:
>   revision walk setup failed

I have no idea when this started and I can't see this commit on github.

Answer (score 5):

For me it was one of git *objects* is damaged (likely after one system crash). To define problems in the repo start `git-fsck` (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck) and this will show problems with objects tree in your repository.

Unfortunately I don't know easy solution to fix it. From my side the easiest way appeared to be clone the original repo to some temporary location and then completely replace (remove old, add new) `.git` directory in my damaged one.

**BUT be careful doing this:** you will **lose** your *local un-pushed commits* (but working tree would be still fine, so it would look like after `git reset --mixed`), *index*, *local repository configuration*, *stashes*. Probably you can try to replace (better totally remove and add) just `.git/objects` directory, in this case you can save your index and local configuration (but **not** un-pushed changes and stashes).

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by running `git fetch --unshallow` on the offending repository.

Comment: I realize this is old, but when I try this command I get "--unshallow on a complete repository does not make sense"

Comment: `git --unshallow` is used when you sync a repo and don't want to get all of its commit history, but just the last n ones ( e.g `--depth=n`). For big repos this is particularly useful as it speeds up the sync process (fetch and pull). The unshallow command fetches the commits that were left behind during the repo init; so if the repo was already entirely synced, makes no sense to unshallow it, as there are no commits left to get.

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete my project and [clone the repository again](https://help.github.com/en/articles/cloning-a-repository).

PS: This may have been caused by me copying about 20 repos from my old laptop to my new one.  All of the other repos work (so far).